# WINAPI cursor click position on application window

Tags: c++, windows, api, winapi, qt5.4

I need to write a small program that can know where the user click the button or somehow on a application windows whatever the application windows change the size .

Through use the windows API, now I can only get the global cursor click position.

I find a small program from china that have similar function using AHK to implement it. Maybe the author use this ([WinGetPos](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinGetPos.htm)) see the image below:

[image]

So, Is the any windows api or other QT5, C++ function can help me get the application windows cursor click position. (I develop in QT5)

post some code on here:

```
GetCursorPos (&screenpoint);
hwndFoundWindow = WindowFromPoint (screenpoint);
mp.DisplayInfoOnFoundWindow(QString::fromLocal8Bit("L"), hwndFoundWindow, pMouseStruct->pt.x, pMouseStruct->pt.y);
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: want to detect something that this program use in lab's platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`ScreenToClient` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162952(v=vs.85).aspx) in the Windows API can be used to convert from screen coordinates to window (client area) coordinates. You will need to know the HWND of your application window.

Comment: i try this function today morning, but seem looks like same is global cursor click position. Maybe i use wrong way, i'll try more

Comment: @geraldlim this function is designed to convert from a global cursor position to a position relative to the window corner.